# Single network share with directories from multiple drives

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, network-shares, media

I have music and videos across multiple drives and would like to create a single share that has these directories available in a single share rather than multiple drive shares. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with junctions. There are a couple ways to go about doing this, an easy way via the GUI would be to go in to the Disk Management MMC, right click on the relevant partition, select Change Drive Letter And Paths, click the Add Button, select the Mount In The Following Empty NTFS Folder radio button, clicking the Browse button to select the folder you want the disk to be mounted to. This will create an additional mount point. Although in my picture there is a single directory mount point there is no reason why you couldn't have one (or more) drive letter and/or directory mount points.

[image]

You can also use the Microsoft SysInternals Junction utility to do the same thing from the command line. In case you dont want the root level of the 2nd disk to be mounted in a subdirectory of the 1st disk, you can use this utility to create a junction between subdirectories on different disks (or the same disk).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx